# Janus RTC: RTMP broadcast viewed in WebRTC

Tags: janus-gateway

Is it possible to broadcast/publish an RTMP stream from mobile such as Android, sent to Janus gateway (media server) and viewed thru webrtc in the web app?

Also can somebody share what is the advantage of such approach if there are any?